# What type of images to use for GWT (Google Web Toolkit)So I'm trying to display

Tags: image, gwt, import

So I'm trying to display an image using GWT, which I assume should be very simple. All the googling I've done insists that the followng will work:

`contentPane = new JPanel();`

`contentPane.setLayout(null);`

`Image image = new Image("lib/line.gif");`

`contentPane.add(image);`

The sample code I've found makes no mention of any imports. I think they assume people are smart enough to know that stuff without being told it :P

Eclipse points to an error at both Image terms, asking me to import java.awt.image, but if I do so, I get both "Cannot instantiate the type Image" A the 2nd Image, and "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Image)".

Is there some other place I can import image from? I have a feeling I am importing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

you have to import **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image**
and your image must be present in lib folder.than write your code.

Image image = new Image("lib/line.gif");

Answer (score 0):

*JPanel* is a *javax.swing* component. You have to use a GWT container, such as [SimplePanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html) or [VerticalPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html). Try this:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

public class ImageSampleMain implements EntryPoint {

   public void onModuleLoad() {
      Image image = new Image();
      image.setUrl("test.png");

      VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
      panel.add(image);

      RootPanel.get().add(panel);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For GWT you must place your image into a folder in your project library.

I use the same folder as my CSS and main HTML file.

To keep your project neat I recommend creating a sub folder in the this folder called images.

Then reference your image in the code.

`Image myImage = new Image("images/filename.png");`

Then add the image to your contentPanel

`contentPanel.add(myImage);`

As stated in an answer above the Image type you need to import is

`import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;`